# how can i get between two tags conntent and replace at specefic text line by line

Tags: regex, get, tags

For example i want replace between `<title></title>` content to `<-PostTitle->` line by line.

```
<item>
  <title>anastasia</title>     no <-PostTitle->  matter bro <-PostTitle->  im ok
  <description></description>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
</item>
<item>
  <title>nura</title>   how are <-PostTitle-> you im <-PostTitle->  fine
  <description></description>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
</item>
```

and then show:

```
<item>
  <title>anastasia</title>     no anastasia  matter bro anastasia  im ok
  <description></description>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
</item>
<item>
  <title>nura</title>   how are nura you im nura  fine
  <description></description>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex you can capture what's between the 2 `<-PostTitle->` and then use those capture groups in the replace in a different order.

**Regex pattern :** `(<title>(.*)<\/title>.*)<-PostTitle->(.*)<-PostTitle->`

**Replace by :** `$1$2$3$2`

**Javascript Example:**

```js
let str = `<item>
  <title>anastasia</title>     no <-PostTitle->  matter bro <-PostTitle->  im ok
  <description></description>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
</item>
<item>
  <title>nura</title>   how are <-PostTitle-> you im <-PostTitle->  fine
  <description></description>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
</item>`;

const re = /(<title>(.*)<\/title>.*)<-PostTitle->(.*)<-PostTitle->/gm;
const subst = '$1$2$3$2';

let result = str.replace(re, subst);

console.log(result);
```

It's a quite basic regex, so it should work with most regex engines used in other programming languages or tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to find this. To identify each title, you can do this.

```
Match m = regex.Match(inputString, @".*<title>(.*)<\/title>.*(?=<title>.*)";
string titleContent = m.Value.ToString();
```

Then replace each placeholder with the title content.

```
str.replace(inputString, "<\-PostTitle\->", titleContent)
```